# Time outputting 1970-01-01 if null?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, time, null

I have a connected database from MSSQL which has the value of date, but it also outputs hours.

I have set `Y-M-D` to remove it, however, if the user has not yet resigned, it is null. But the output shows 1970 even though I have not set anything in it.

If I remove `date(y-m-d etcetc...)`, it shows no value. But if the user resigned, it will still show the hours which is annoying.

What is the possible solution for this?

```
<label>Enrolled since</label>
<input value="<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res->DateHired)); ?>" type="text" name="enrolled" readonly/>

<label>Not Enrolled since</label>
<input value="<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res->ResignationDate)); ?>" type="text" name="notenrolled" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `null` to `strtotime`, you will get `false`. Now, `date('Y-m-d', false)` is same as `date('Y-m-d', null)` or `date('Y-m-d', 0)` and always represents [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If you do not want a value in your `value`, you are to explicitly use a condition:

```
if($res->DateHired)
{
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res->DateHired));
}
```